# Suppress keyboard after setting text with Android uiautomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Using uiautomator for Android I am able to set text in a text field but not able to then close the keyboard.  With some phones when in lanscape mode the keyboard takes up the whole screen and 'Done' must be tapped to get out of that view.  If I can suppress the keyboard then I can run uiautomator in both landscape and portrait without issue.

```
new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Enter Text")).click();
new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText").instance(0)).setText("sample text");

// This is where I need to suppress the keyboard to view the app instead of just the keyboard itself.

new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Submit")).click();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally clicking the Back-key will dismiss the keyboard.

```
getUiDevice().pressBack();
```

Comment: This works except for cases when the app in portrait mode and the keyboard does not need 'done' to be tapped.  So I made a special case for landscape only.

Comment: is there any intelligent solution? ie. one that involves checking whether the keyboard is shown, whether it obstructs a button to be clicked etc.

Answer (score 10):

This is quite an old question but with UiAutomator 2.0 it is possible to correctly and completely answer the question and thus here it is.

The optimal would be:

```
if (isKeyboardOpened()) {
    UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()).pressBack();
}
```

But so far the problem was how to implement isKeyboardOpened().

As UiAutomator 2.0 is based on instrumentation, and thus we have access to UiAutomation, we can verify if there are any input windows present on the screen:

```
boolean isKeyboardOpened() {
    UiAutomation automation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation();
    for (AccessibilityWindowInfo window : automation.getWindows()) {
        if (window.getType() == AccessibilityWindowInfo.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Somewhere in initialization code, make sure you execute this code, otherwise `.getWindow()` will always return an empty list:

```
    UiAutomation automation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = automation.getServiceInfo();
    info.flags |=  AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS;
    automation.setServiceInfo(info);
```

Comment: I am trying to make this work but it cannot resolve the symbol `Constants`. Quick fixes through Alt+Enter import `SyncStateContract.Constants` which does not contain a `uiAuto` field. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Ok I found it out. I needed to get the UiAutomation object through instrumentation: `UiAutomation uiautomation = getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation();`

Comment: The Constants was my bad (I copy-pasted from a project and forgot to change that part, sorry). I'll edit the reply.

Comment: This does not always work. The keyboard is present while this function returns false.

Comment: in which situation?

Comment: I'm also getting false, because the `getWindows()` is always empty. Default API 21 and 24 emulators. I'm using `androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0`. I found that the flag needs to be set in order for this to work, updated the answer with this info. I'm guessing your original `Constants.uiAuto` initialization was doing this in a `static` block?

Answer (score 3):

Seems very wrong, but it gets the job done.

```
public static final int KEYBOARD_WAIT_TIME = 111;

Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard();
sleep(AutomatedTestConfig.KEYBOARD_WAIT_TIME);
```

Answer (score 2):

I used your code, just added \n on the end of inserted text. That simulate 'enter', but keyboard is still appeared, so you need pressBack() to dismiss keyb.

```
new UiObject(new UiSelector()
   .className("android.widget.EditText")
   .instance(0))
   .setText("sample text\n");
getUiDevice().pressBack();
```

There is more elegant solution:

```
new UiObject(new UiSelector()
   .className("android.widget.EditText")
   .instance(0))
   .setText("sample text");
getUiDevice().pressEnter();
```

Comment: Hi, this is quite an old question and it's not really clear that you are answering the question directly or adding more to the answers that exist.  If you think this is a technique of general interest, it is OK on here to ask a new question and answer it yourself.

Comment: @JRichardSnape as far as I see they just explained how they go to the answer, and gave a very good solution actually, compared to the other "back" solutions, because it commits the text field value as a person would.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Yeah - fair enough - I was perhaps being too harsh there because it does add the more elegant technique.  Came up in a review queue 8 years ago, so I can't really recall my thinking then!!

Answer (score 0):

Final after lot of work I found follow way to do this.
The problem is call `getUIDevice().pressBack()` can break the test if no soft keyboard was display.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
    getUIDevice().pressBack();
}
```

That will only press back if keyboard was displayed.

Comment: I tried this and the result is always false, both when the keyboard is opened and closed. Do you have any idea of why this is?

Answer (score -1):

Try `DummyIME` and run the `uiautomator` tool with `-e disable_ime true` option.
`DummyIME` resides in [Android git repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing).

1. Clone source code of `DummyIME`:

   ```
   git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing
   ```
2. Build and install `DummyIME` (You may change `android-18`):

   ```
   cd testing/uiautomator/utils/DummyIME
   android update project -p . -t android-18
   ant clean debug install
   ```
3. Run your tests using the uiautomator framework with `-e disable_ime true` option.

   ```
   adb shell uiautomator runtest <JARS> -e disable_ime true -c <CLASSES>
   ```

Note that you must restore settings of the default IME in your tested device
because it is automatically changed into `DummyIME` after running the test.